# Does any column match requirement?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a count of stems by tree species for different plots.

```
structure(list(Plot = c(1, 2), Pine = c(0, 430), Spruce = c(708, 
1241), Birch = c(119, 48), Aspen = c(0, 0), Salix = c(0, 0), 
    Rowan = c(0, 0), Alnus = c(0, 0), stem_sum = c(827, 1719)), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L), groups = structure(list(.rows = structure(list(1L, 2L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")), class = c("rowwise_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

What I want to do is use dplyr 1.0 convention to mutate a new column, "Main species", if any of the tree species columns exceed 80% of the stem_sum of that plot.

My thought process:

```
df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(`Main species`= c_across(Pine:Alnus, if(.. / stem/sum >= 0.8, paste(...))
```

How can I modify this code such that if there are more than one column which fulfils the requirement, the output will be "Mixed"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(Plot, stem_sum)) %>%
  arrange(Plot, desc(value)) %>%
  group_by(Plot) %>%
  mutate(pct = value/stem_sum,
         main_species = case_when(
           pct > 0.8 & pct == max(pct) ~ name,
           pct == max(pct) ~ "mixed"
           )
         ) %>% ungroup() %>%
  fill(main_species, .direction = "down") %>%
  select(-pct) %>%
  pivot_wider()
```

Comment: Jakub elegant solution!

Answer (score 2):

You can use :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(Main_Species = if(any(c_across(Pine:Alnus) >= 0.8 * stem_sum)) 
                           'Mixed' else 'Not Mixed')

#   Plot  Pine Spruce Birch Aspen Salix Rowan Alnus stem_sum Main_Species
#  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl> <chr>       
#1     1     0    708   119     0     0     0     0      827 Mixed       
#2     2   430   1241    48     0     0     0     0     1719 Not Mixed
```

Or in base R :

```
df$Main_species <- ifelse(rowSums(df[2:8] >= df$stem_sum * 0.8) > 0, 
                          'Mixed', 'Not Mixed')
```

Comment: Hi Ronak! Thank you for your quick reply. This is close to what I meant, but maybe I worded it poorly. If it is "Not Mixed" I want it to state the species that fulfils the requirement? E.g. "Spruce" or "Pine"?

Comment: @Silviculturalist "Not mixed" is when no species fulfils the requirement then how will you have species name there?